# can't register objects using unity 2.0

Tags: unity-container

I created a web service recently and am using unity to inject my object dependencies. My composition root is the Application_Start in the web services and am using the web.config to do my object to interface mappings.  Everything was working fine, however after i loaded my project into tfs i keep getting an error stating that it cant resolve one of the interfaces.  I removed the code to register my objects from the web.config and regsistered them in code instead to test and it all works fine.  Any ideas what the problem is.  Any ideas how i can troubleshoot this problem.

Before TFs :-

```
        UnityContainer uContainer = new UnityContainer();
        UnityConfigurationSection Section = (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity");
        Section.Configure(uContainer, "CentralRepositoryContainer");
        Application["uContainer"] = uContainer;
```

Amended code which works fine :-

```
        UnityContainer uContainer = new UnityContainer();
        uContainer.RegisterType<ICentralRepositoryLifeTimehelper, CentralRepositoryLifeTimeHelper>();
        uContainer.RegisterType<IJobsHandler, JobsHandler>();
        Application["uContainer"] = uContainer;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the problem, but to troubleshoot print out all the Unity containers registrations and see what's missing/changed.

Use the code sample from [Retrieving Container Registration Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660863%28v=PandP.20%29.aspx)